# VScode adding tick to dockerRun command

Tags: python, docker, docker-container, vscode-tasks

I'm trying to get the below to run a docker container command via VScode.

Within tasks.json I have:

```
{
    "label": "docker-run: debug",
    "type": "docker-run",
    "dependsOn": [
        "docker-build"
    ],
    "python": {
        "module": "simply.py"
    },
    "dockerRun": {
        "command": "python3 simply.py",
        
    }
},
```

Which I would expect to be run as

`docker container run [unrelated arguments] python3 simply.py`

Where  `python3 simply.py` is the command I want to run

Instead I am getting

`` docker container run [unrelated arguments] python3` simply.py ``

I'm not sure where VScode is generating this tick after python3 but the result is my code doesn't run.

An example of `dockerRun` with `python3` within `command` might help indicate what I'm doing wrong.

Also running `docker container run [unrelated arguments] python3 simply.py` in the terminal works fine.

Thanks

extra:
Not sure if relevant but my launch.json is:

```
{
    "name": "Docker: DEV",
    "type": "docker",
    "request": "launch",
    "preLaunchTask": "docker-run: debug",
    "python": {
        "pathMappings": [
            {
                "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
                "remoteRoot": "/app"
            }
        ],
    },
},
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed itself upon closing and opening VScode